# interchange variable names based on a separator in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have variable names

`Sales_Ab Cost_Bcfg Revenue_Cshsh`

I would like the output  data to look like

`Ab_Sales Bcfg_Cost Cshsh_Revenue`

Im aware sub and gsub can be used in some form but Im not versed with the exact technicality required to code that.

Comment: Just do `sub("(\\w+)_(\\w+)", '\\2_\\1', v1)`

Comment: Can you explain this code?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @akrun Should we really encourage people to ask question like this by answering? Wouldn't it be better if we first help to improve the question?

Comment: @Alex I was supposed to leave it as a comment when the OP asked to explain it.  I would assume the OP to be a newbie in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `sub` to match the first word, capture as a group (`(\\w+)`) followed by a `_` and then capture the next word (`(...)`), replace it with the backreference.  Here we switch the order of the backreference to 2nd backreference followed by the `_` and then the 1st.

```
sub("(\\w+)_(\\w+)", '\\2_\\1', v1)
#[1] "Ab_Sales"      "Bcfg_Cost"     "Cshsh_Revenue"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('Sales_Ab',  'Cost_Bcfg', 'Revenue_Cshsh')
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, so is this limited to two groups or we can extended it to a third or fourth as well?

Comment: @user36176  It is not limited to two groups, but you can extend it to third or fourth.  Only thing is `(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)` and in replacement let's say 2 4, 1, 3, order then `"\\2_\\4_\\1_\\3"`